# How to horizontal/vertical combine two math symbols?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, symbols, vertical-alignment, amsmath

This is an absolutely minor/cosmetic problem. I can e.g. use `stackrel` so combine two math-symbols vertically. This is nice for `\stackrel{!}{=}`. But how to do this horizontally? I want to combine (only once, no newcommand necessary) the colon and an equivalence sign. I found the option `\mathrel{: \equiv}` which allows different versions like:

```
:\equiv  \quad \mathrel{: \equiv} \quad \mathrel{: \!\! \equiv} \quad \mathrel{: \!\! \!\! \!\! \equiv}
```

[image]

So I can shift the horizontal position. But like to achieve that the colon is centered regarding the vertical position. Like the blue version:

[image]

Again: if I use `stackrel` is combines two symbols vertically and centered! If I use `mathrel` is combines two symbols horizontally but not centered somehow.

I am eager to see your solutions.

Comment: `\mathop{:}` centers the colon, so `\mathrel{\mathop{:}}\equiv` for instance would work.

Comment: @Manuel I do not see any difference to `:\equiv`. Could you elaborate a bit more on your suggestion, please! Why should `\mathop` centre something? This would be wrong IMO

Comment: @LaRiFaRi That's the way `\mathop` works, if there's a single atom inside it then it vertically centers the content (good because of, e.g., `\sum` or `\int`).

Comment: @Manuel But I can not see an effect in this example. Please write an answer showing this effect. Would be interesting as it is much shorter than mine. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I don't know what happens, but just look at the defintion of `\vcentcolon` which, if I'm not mistaken, does exactly this. The thing is that `\mathrel{\mathop:}\equiv` works while `\mathrel{\mathop{:}}\equiv` doesn't. No idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Completely new update**:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\AtBeginDocument{\providecommand*\colonequiv{\vcentcolon\mspace{-1.2mu}\equiv}}

\begin{document}
\[A\colonequiv B\]
%\[A\coloneqq B\] % for prove of consistency 
%\[A\coloneq B\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Old version** (I believe, misunderstood):

Super hacky, but it works:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\[A\mathrel{\mathmakebox[\widthof{$\equiv$}]{\mathclap{:}\mathclap{\equiv}}}B\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want it to be centred vertically as well, you may want to do `\mathclap{\raisebox{.34pt}{:}}` instead. Both symbols do have the same height (speaking of their surrounding boxes) but they are designed on different height levels. Therefore I do not see a solution for "soft coded" centring.

---

You did not want a command for this, but as it is so long, I would clearly advise to code one if this is used more than once.

Comment: I've never understood why `mathtools` defines `\coloneqq` as `\mathrel{\vcentcolon\mkern{-1.2mu}=}` where `\vcentcolon\mspace{-1.2mu}=` suffices (`\vcentcolon` is already a relation atom).

Comment: @egreg Strange indeed. I thought, `\vcentcolon` isn't (due to that implementation) but it clearly is. I will report that. Some reason for your using `\mspace` (which I have never seen before)?

Comment: `\mspace` is added by `amsmath` for consistency with `\hspace`. It does `\mskip`, but in case there's no stretch or shrink component this is basically the same as `\mkern`.

Comment: I was looking for the 'Completely new update'. Thank you

Comment: @Mac Glad to hear that. You are welcome!