# How to type a notation as same as the below pictue

Tags: symbols

I want to type a notation as same as the below pictue
[image]

How must I do?

Please help me!

Comment: You are not looking for `:\equiv`, are you?

Comment: but :\equiv is not satisfy

Comment: It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. Currently it is not at all clear what you are trying to do and, as result, your question to almost certainly going to be closed because it is "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: what is the meaning of this symbol.  has it appeared in a published document?  if so, it can be submitted to unicode for consideration.  (i will be happy to do that, if the necessary documentation is provided.)

Answer (score 3):

There is no exact symbol like this, but you can assemble a colon to an `\equiv` with adjusting the spacing as follows. Caveat: this is highly dependent on the font chosen, so the spacing can change according to the document font.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\dequiv}{:\mkern-2mu\equiv}

\[ 
  Q(x)\dequiv\prod_{i=1}^{2017}(x+i),\quad 
  f(x)\dequiv\sum_{i=1}^{2016}\frac{c_i}{(x+i)(x+i+1)}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ummm, interesting! Should we mark this duplicate?

Comment: I honestly do not know. (I am rather certain it is a duplicate, but as long as we do not know if the question concerns (a) the colon-equiv or (b) the red circle, it will be hard to tell of which question it is a duplicate...)

Answer (score 2):

I am confused and will be happy to remove this post. You are tagging the question `annotations`, so maybe you are wondering how to draw a circle? Just let me know if any of this is satisfactory. **UPDATE**: Using `\colonequiv` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262881/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\AtBeginDocument{\providecommand*\colonequiv{\vcentcolon\mkern-1.2mu\equiv}}

\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
\ifmmode%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$%\tikznodestyle 
  #2$};
\else
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}

\newcommand{\Kringel}[2][]{
\tikznode{X}{#2}\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=0.4pt,#1,fit=(X)]{};}}
\begin{document}
\[ Q(x)\Kringel[red,thick]{\colonequiv}\prod\limits_{i=1}^{2017}(x+i),\quad
f(x)\Kringel[red,thick]{\colonequiv}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2016}
\frac{c_i}{(x+i)(x+i+1)}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. I will still be happy to remove this.

Comment: Instead of `\mspace{-1.2mu}`, consider using `\mkern-1.2mu`. The former inserts (negative) breakable space, the latter inserts unbreakable space.